# Implementing IDisposable using StructureMap for a WPF Prism application

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, structuremap, idisposable

We are currently using Prism and Structuremap for our WPF application and want to implement the IDisposable pattern. 
All examples that I found for using StructureMap and IDisposable are implementantions for web projects (using HttpContext etc).
For example, we are using an unmanaged ressource in our ViewModel and in certain services. It is not possible to put this ressource in a using{} block, because they are often called in each class.

In our situation we have a viewmodel which is created by StructureMap. StructureMap injects a business logic object into this viewmodel. The business logic object holds a reference to an object that implements IDisposable. Because of that our business logic class has to implement IDispsable, too.

Our problem is, that we have no idea, how we could dispose the business logic class. The view model class shouldn't dispose the business logic because it didn't create the business logic object. In fact StructureMap should dispose the business logic class, but we have no idea how tell StructureMap to dispose the business logic class as soon as possible (when the user closes the view in the application).

This wouldn't be a problem in a web application because you could tell StructureMap to dispose the object via DisposeAndClear when the requests ends. In a WPF / Prism Application there is no "Request end", so what would be the best solution in this scenario?

Because the object that is held by the business logic class could use a huge amount of memory, we have to make really sure to dispose the object as soon as the view is closed and not when the thread ends.

Any help would be appreciated!